# Finding the lonely integer - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, indexof

Consider the array [1,2,2]

The array contains two unique values: 1, 2

The array contains duplicate values: 2

The lonely integer is 1

How can the lonely integer be returned?

Comment: And if there are more than 1 "lonely" integer? Would all of them be returned?

Comment: Hey, @PeterKA, yes that is the goal.

Comment: @GertArnold - yes it does.

Answer (score 6):

For an array where you only care about grabbing the first integer which is lonely, you can check if the indexOf and lastIndexOf are the same. If they are, then it's lonely.

```js
const array = [2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4];

const findLonely = (arr) => {
    for (const num of arr) {
        if (arr.indexOf(num) === arr.lastIndexOf(num)) return num;
    }
    return 'No lonely integers.';
};

console.log(findLonely(array));
```

If you have an array that has multiple lonely values, you can use this method to find all of the lonely values:

```js
const array = [2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 6, 8, 8, 9];

const findAllLonely = (arr) => {
    const map = {};

    arr.forEach((num) => {
        // Keep track of the number of time each number appears in the array
        if (!map[num]) return (map[num] = 1);
        map[num]++;
    });

    // Filter through and only keep the values that have 1 instance
    return Object.keys(map).filter((key) => {
        return map[key] === 1;
    });
};

console.log(findAllLonely(array)); // expect [1, 6, 9]
```

Comment: This is a better approach. I appreciate the feedback. Thank you!

Comment: @MikeySherm No problem)) If you ever find yourself writing 3 loops for something as simple as this, it's usually a good idea to reevaluate haha.

Comment: Here's more info on why not to use 3 loops: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @MikeySherm yup yup, big O :D

Answer (score 6):

```js
const array = [0,1,2,2,1,5,4,3,4,3,2];

let lonely = array.filter((item,index)=> array.indexOf(item) === array.lastIndexOf(item));
console.log(lonely);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Working Demo :**

```js
// Array with duplicates
const arrWithDuplicates = [1, 2, 2];
 
var result = arrWithDuplicates.sort().filter((x,i,arr) => x !== arr[i+1] && x !== arr[i-1]);
console.log(result); // [1]
```

Comment: It is working fine for `[0, 0, 1, 2, 1]` as well. Here is the working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/8Lnbvu90/

Answer (score 2):

For each element your can use `.filter()` to help count the how many times the element is repeated. Then use `.filter()` again to return only those elements that appear once.

```js
const nums = [1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,8,8];

const singles = nums.filter(
    //count how many times each element appears
    num => nums.filter(n => n === num)
    //return only those with freq. of 1
    .length === 1
);

console.log( singles );
//OUTPUT: [  1,  3,  6 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a 'for' loop with the filter function to loop through the array and only return the value that appears once

```
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 2, 1];
let unique;

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(a.filter(x => x == arr[i]).length == 1) {
        unique = arr[i]
    }
}

return unique;
```

Answer (score 0):

O(n) complexity

```
function lonelyinteger(a) {
        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            const count = a.filter((v) => v === a[i]).length;
            if (count === 1) {
                console.log(a[i]);
                return a[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also add some explanation of the answer, see how do I write a good answer [answer].

Answer (score 0):

the code below solves the challenge with O(n) complexity

```
 function lonelyinteger(a) {
    
    let result;
    a.every((e)=>{
        if(a.filter(x=>x==e).length==1) {
            result = e;
            return false;
        }return true;
    })
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score -1):

If there is multiple unique number in an `array = [1,2,3,4,5,3,2,1]` here `4 and 5 both are unique` ,there is two lonely integer so the output should be like this `result = [4,5]`. In case of single unique integer we can return the result as `result = [3] or result = 3`. The below code snippet will solve both the scenario.

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,3,2,1]

let result = []

array.every(e => {
  if(array.filter(x => x == e).length == 1) {
 result.push(e)
} 
return true
})

console.log(result)
```

**`Explanation:` step by step**

1. Your desire array from where you need to get the lonely integer.
2. We defined result as an array.
3. You can use simple `for loop` or array `forEach` ([learn about forEach](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array-foreach/)).
4. We are using array `filter` method ([learn about filter](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array-filter/)) to get our work done. Here `array.filter(x => x == e)` this will result when the value of e is 1 (first element of the array) then the output will be [1,1].
   So for 1 the `.length == 1` will return false. This process will continue to get false and the if condition will not get executed until a the **'e'** became 4 (4th element of the main array).
5. When **'e'** became 4 then the result of `array.filter(x => x == 4)` will be [4] so the condition `array.filter(x => x == e).length == 1` will be `true` and the if condition will execute. And inside that we are pushing the value 4 to the result array. You can add a next line `return false` to stop the execution and you will get only one single lonely integer.
6. `return true` is required here only if you're using the `every` method ([learn about array `every` method](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-every/))

Play with the code to get better understanding or comment if you've some question about this solution. **Please give a up-vote if this answer is helpful.**